# Trying To Get Key From a Child Value In Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I Have String From Which I am Trying To Get The Key So I Can Use That Key To retrive Some More Value At That Key Location.
This Is My Query Code -

```
private void xyz()
{
    Query t1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("leaderboard").child(matchnumber).child(conlocation).orderByChild("teamname").equalTo(name1);
    t1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            Toast.makeText(Leaderboard.this, key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

This is My Database Data Structure.

[image]

So I Am Trying To Get The Key 1,2,3,4 But I am Getting Contest1 As a Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about loop through the children:

```
......
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
//this runs for every key
String key = ds.getKey();
Toast.makeText(Leaderboard.this, key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}

......
```

**For the comment:**

```
.........

for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
//this runs for every key
String key = ds.getKey();
sendKey(key);
........


//new method under your private method
public void sendKey(String key){

//do what ever with the key or keys


}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Will try it in some time.

Comment: Will i get that key number?

Comment: The loop will run n times, n being the number of child nodes under contest node. So you should.

Comment: Thanks for your responce.gonna check in some time.I just want to run loop before retriving key right?

Comment: Try and see, so we know whats going on,

Comment: Ok will try now

Comment: Perfect! I Got the Key.

Comment: GoodLuck, glad to help.

Comment: Can i Ask You 1 More Question?

Comment: yeah ask but please in the scope of the question, otherwise ask a new question.

Comment: Current Operation Was in a private method I just Want To Pass This String Key To another Method.Can You refer Any Simple Post?

Comment: instead of the toast message or under it pass the key to a public method .

Comment: i Dont Know How To Pass And Retrive In Another Method